# How to change SharePoint Site language programmatically using spfx extension

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

it there way to change language dropdown of SharePoint site such as English to German using spfx solution ?

I am looking function like

```
pagecontext.setLanguage(1031);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any method like this in the spfx context.
However, I see that when you change the language from the dropdown a cookie is set with a new value. Nevertheless, the culture in the spfx context continue being the default one of the SharePoint user.

For example, this is the value of the "siteLangPref" cookie when you have two open diferent SharePoint sites in the browser and with different selected languages:

```
6ac9ad3e-91f3-4f62-a832-c468ea800fe1_fc2ea1ba-d195-41d2-a736-c9dd31d71d10_en-us.0691ee57-ad00-4895-8bf7-1df527306d7c_91f16404-3907-42d3-8c4d-9450e3f32ca1_fr-fr
```

```
[site-id-1]_[web-id-1]_[selected-language].[site-id-2]_[web-id-2]_[selected-language]
```

If it helps, this is my code (first attempt :P). I manage en-us as default and fr-fr as alt:

```
  private switchToLanguage(context: ApplicationCustomizerContext, lang: string) {
    const cookieName = "siteLangPref";
    let url = window.location.href;
    const currentCookieValue = Utils.getCookie(cookieName);
    const sitesValues: string[] = currentCookieValue ? currentCookieValue.split(".") : [];
    const siteId = context.pageContext.site.id;
    const webId = context.pageContext.web.id;
    const siteKey = `${siteId}_${webId}`;
    const siteValue = `${siteKey}_${lang}`;
    const currentSiteValueIndex = sitesValues.findIndex(v => v.toLowerCase().startsWith(siteKey.toLowerCase()));
    
    if(currentSiteValueIndex !== -1) {
      sitesValues[currentSiteValueIndex] = siteValue;
    } else {
      sitesValues.push(siteValue);
    }

    const newCookieValue = sitesValues.join(".");

    const today = new Date();
    const oneYear = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    document.cookie = `${cookieName}=${newCookieValue};path=/;expires=${oneYear.toUTCString()}`;

    if(url.indexOf("/fr/") !== -1 && lang === "en-us")
      url = url.replace("/fr/", "/");
    
      window.location.href = url;
  }
```